# Windows error sound when key enter is pressed in a combobox

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio, audio, combobox

With the code hereunder, if I hit the 'e' key in the combobox and select "Elvira Woolfolk" (or any other name !) with the down key and then validate with the enter key, windows plays an error sound very annoying. I tried to remove it with :

```
e.Handled = true
e.SuppressKeyPress = true
```

but without succes. I tried many other solutions that i found on the internet but no one worked.

I tried with a simple combobox and the problem is the same, when the enter key is pressed, the error sound is played.

Any idea for removing this sound ?

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Linq.Expressions
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim testbox As New AutoCompleteComboBox.SuggestComboBox
    Me.Controls.Add(testbox)
    testbox.DataSource = New List(Of String) From {"Janean Mcgaha", "Tama Gaitan", "Jacque Tinnin", "Elvira Woolfolk", "Fransisca Owens", "Minnie Ardoin", _
    "Renay Bentler", "Joye Boyter", "Jaime Flannery", "Maryland Arai", "Walton Edelstein", "Nereida Storrs", _
    "Theron Zinn", "Katharyn Estrella", "Alline Dubin", "Edra Bhatti", "Willa Jeppson", "Chelsea Revel", _
    "Sonya Lowy", "Danelle Kapoor"}
End Sub
End Class

Namespace AutoCompleteComboBox
Public Class SuggestComboBox
    Inherits ComboBox
#Region "fields and properties"

    Private ReadOnly _suggLb As New ListBox() With {.Visible = False, .TabStop = False}
    Private ReadOnly _suggBindingList As New BindingList(Of String)()
    Private _propertySelector As Expression(Of Func(Of ObjectCollection, IEnumerable(Of String)))
    Private _propertySelectorCompiled As Func(Of ObjectCollection, IEnumerable(Of String))
    Private _filterRule As Expression(Of Func(Of String, String, Boolean))
    Private _filterRuleCompiled As Func(Of String, Boolean)
    Private _suggestListOrderRule As Expression(Of Func(Of String, String))
    Private _suggestListOrderRuleCompiled As Func(Of String, String)

    Public Property SuggestBoxHeight() As Integer
        Get
            Return _suggLb.Height
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            If value > 0 Then
                _suggLb.Height = value
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' If the item-type of the ComboBox is not string,
    ''' you can set here which property should be used
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property PropertySelector() As Expression(Of Func(Of ObjectCollection, IEnumerable(Of String)))
        Get
            Return _propertySelector
        End Get
        Set(value As Expression(Of Func(Of ObjectCollection, IEnumerable(Of String))))
            If value Is Nothing Then
                Return
            End If
            _propertySelector = value
            _propertySelectorCompiled = value.Compile()
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<summary>
    ''' Lambda-Expression to determine the suggested items
    ''' (as Expression here because simple lamda (func) is not serializable)
    ''' <para>default: case-insensitive contains search</para>
    ''' <para>1st string: list item</para>
    ''' <para>2nd string: typed text</para>
    '''</summary>
    Public Property FilterRule() As Expression(Of Func(Of String, String, Boolean))
        Get
            Return _filterRule
        End Get
        Set(value As Expression(Of Func(Of String, String, Boolean)))
            If value Is Nothing Then
                Return
            End If
            _filterRule = value
            _filterRuleCompiled = Function(item) value.Compile()(item, Text)
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<summary>
    ''' Lambda-Expression to order the suggested items
    ''' (as Expression here because simple lamda (func) is not serializable)
    ''' <para>default: alphabetic ordering</para>
    '''</summary>
    Public Property SuggestListOrderRule() As Expression(Of Func(Of String, String))
        Get
            Return _suggestListOrderRule
        End Get
        Set(value As Expression(Of Func(Of String, String)))
            If value Is Nothing Then
                Return
            End If
            _suggestListOrderRule = value
            _suggestListOrderRuleCompiled = value.Compile()
        End Set
    End Property

#End Region

    ''' <summary>
    ''' ctor
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub New()
        ' set the standard rules:
        _filterRuleCompiled = Function(s) s.ToLower().Contains(Text.Trim().ToLower())
        _suggestListOrderRuleCompiled = Function(s) s
        _propertySelectorCompiled = Function(collection) collection.Cast(Of String)()

        _suggLb.DataSource = _suggBindingList
        AddHandler _suggLb.Click, AddressOf SuggLbOnClick

        AddHandler ParentChanged, AddressOf OnParentChanged
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' the magic happens here ;-)
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    Protected Overrides Sub OnTextChanged(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnTextChanged(e)

        If Not Focused Then
            Return
        End If

        _suggBindingList.Clear()
        _suggBindingList.RaiseListChangedEvents = False
        _propertySelectorCompiled(Items).Where(_filterRuleCompiled).OrderBy(_suggestListOrderRuleCompiled).ToList().ForEach(AddressOf _suggBindingList.Add)
        _suggBindingList.RaiseListChangedEvents = True
        _suggBindingList.ResetBindings()

        _suggLb.Visible = _suggBindingList.Any()

        If _suggBindingList.Count = 1 AndAlso _suggBindingList.[Single]().Length = Text.Trim().Length Then
            Text = _suggBindingList.[Single]()
            [Select](0, Text.Length)
            _suggLb.Visible = False
        End If
    End Sub

#Region "size and position of suggest box"

    ''' <summary>
    ''' suggest-ListBox is added to parent control
    ''' (in ctor parent isn't already assigned)
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    Private Overloads Sub OnParentChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Parent.Controls.Add(_suggLb)
        Parent.Controls.SetChildIndex(_suggLb, 0)
        _suggLb.Top = Top + Height - 3
        _suggLb.Left = Left + 3
        _suggLb.Width = Width - 20
        _suggLb.Font = New Font("Segoe UI", 9)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnLocationChanged(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLocationChanged(e)
        _suggLb.Top = Top + Height - 3
        _suggLb.Left = Left + 3
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnSizeChanged(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnSizeChanged(e)
        _suggLb.Width = Width - 20
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region "visibility of suggest box"

    Protected Overrides Sub OnLostFocus(e As EventArgs)
        ' _suggLb can only getting focused by clicking (because TabStop is off)
        ' --> click-eventhandler 'SuggLbOnClick' is called
        If Not _suggLb.Focused Then
            HideSuggBox()
        End If
        MyBase.OnLostFocus(e)
    End Sub

    Private Sub SuggLbOnClick(sender As Object, eventArgs As EventArgs)
        Text = _suggLb.Text
        Focus()
    End Sub

    Private Sub HideSuggBox()
        _suggLb.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnDropDown(e As EventArgs)
        HideSuggBox()
        MyBase.OnDropDown(e)
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region "keystroke events"

    ''' <summary>
    ''' if the suggest-ListBox is visible some keystrokes
    ''' should behave in a custom way
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    Protected Overrides Sub OnPreviewKeyDown(e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs)
        If Not _suggLb.Visible Then
            MyBase.OnPreviewKeyDown(e)
            Return
        End If

        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.Down
                If _suggLb.SelectedIndex < _suggBindingList.Count - 1 Then
                    _suggLb.SelectedIndex += 1
                End If
                Return
            Case Keys.Up
                If _suggLb.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
                    _suggLb.SelectedIndex -= 1
                End If
                Return
            Case Keys.Enter
                Text = _suggLb.Text
                [Select](0, Text.Length)
                _suggLb.Visible = False
                Return
            Case Keys.Escape
                HideSuggBox()
                Return
        End Select

        MyBase.OnPreviewKeyDown(e)
    End Sub

    Private Shared ReadOnly KeysToHandle As List(Of Keys) = New List(Of Keys) From {Keys.Down, Keys.Up, Keys.Enter, Keys.Escape}
    Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
        ' the keysstrokes of our interest should not be processed be base class:
        If _suggLb.Visible AndAlso KeysToHandle.Contains(keyData) Then
            Return True
        End If
        Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
    End Function

#End Region
End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Ok, now that I know that there is a lot of code, what about the windows sound ?

Comment: Have you tried this? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982946/how-to-stop-window-error-sound-when-typing-enter-or-esc)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already tried this without succes. I had to translate in vb but I don't know if I did this correctly. This is how I have translated :
    Private Sub ProcessCmdKey(ref As Message, keyData As Keys)
            If (keyData = Keys.Enter) Then
                Me.Hide()
                Return
            End If
        End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. If it can help someone :

```
Private Sub ComboBox1KeyPressed(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs)
    If e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then e.Handled = True
End Sub
```

It works fine, no more error sound when I hit the enter key.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
If keyData = Keys.Enter Then
    Me.Hide()
    Return True
End If

Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

Comment: I'am not sure that me.hide will solve the problem. however, I have fixed the pb last week. If it can help someone :
    Private Sub ComboBox1KeyPressed(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs)
        If e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then e.Handled = True
    End Sub

Comment: @MikaYou can post your conclusion as answer and  click '✔' to mark it as the accepted answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.